# quantile regression+ dummy variable

Tags: r, quantile, quantreg

I used the `quantreg` package in R to compute the quantile regression model.  In the model, dependent Variable(Y) is `NAS_DELAY`, and the independent variable(Xs) are `SEANSON1TO4`, `SEANSON2TO4`, `SEANSON3TO4`.
The model is:

```
NAS_DELAY=aSEANSON1TO4+bSEANSON2TO4+cSEANSON3TO4+d
```

The `SEANSON1TO4`,`SEANSON2TO4`,`SEANSON3TO4` are dummy variables, 0 or 1.  I use R to compute the intercept and  other regression coefficient, but  the result showed that

> "error in rq.fit.br(x,y,tau=tau,....)singular design matrix ;in addition: Warning messages 1:in summary.rq(xi,....):278951 non-positivr fis".

I can't figure out why.

```
"fit2<-summary(rq(NAS_DELAY ~SEASON1TO4+SEASON2TO4+SEASON3TO4,tau=c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5),data=fddata))
Error in base::backsolve(r, x, k = k, upper.tri = upper.tri, transpose = transpose,  :   singular matrix in 'backsolve'. First zero in diagonal [1]"
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In rq.fit.br(x, y, tau = tau, ...) : Solution may be nonunique
2: In rq.fit.br(x, y, tau = tau, ...) : Solution may be nonunique
3: In rq.fit.br(x, y, tau = tau, ...) : Solution may be nonunique
4: In rq.fit.br(x, y, tau = tau, ...) : Solution may be nonunique
5: In rq.fit.br(x, y, tau = tau, ...) : Solution may be nonunique
6: In summary.rq(xi, ...) : 188771 non-positive fis
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Because of the constructed factors in your dataset, the matrix composition is singular.

See explanations of singularity : [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/70910/11388), [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/83859/11388), and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/70700/11388) . Essentially quantreg depends on inverting the data matrix and because of the form of the factors, the matrix is uninvertable.

If you have enough data / if it makes sense for your data, this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18754324/improving-a-badly-conditioned-matrix/19716062#19716062) points to some possible solutions if appropriate for your data.

Answer (score 0):

I had only partially the same problem but this might still help someone. I tried:

```
myFactor <- as.factor(myData$myVariable)
myDummies = model.matrix(~myFactor)
summary.rq(q <- rq(myTarget ~ myOtherPredictor1+myOtherPredictor2+myDummies))
```

This resulted in 
`Error in rq.fit.br(x, y, tau = tau, ...) : Singular design matrix`

However, executing
`summary.rq(q <- rq(myTarget ~ myOtherPredictor1+myOtherPredictor2+myFactor))`

Produced no errors. Converting to dummies before call to rq can be problematic when there are also other predictors.